# Error al instalar pyproj W10

Tags: python

Dentro de mi escritorio virtual (WWII) tengo instalado pandas, bokeh y al instalar pyproj, sale errores.
Inicialmente me pedia Visual c++ 14.0, despues de instalarlo me sale el siguiente error al instalar pyproj.
[image: Captura de error instalacion pyproj en virtualenv]

uso python 3.7.0

[image: lista de programas w10]

Comment: Parece que ese paquete tiene partes escritas en C, por lo que se requiere un compilador C para su instalación. Aunque tü tienes uno, la compilación te está dando problemas, tal vez por falta de bibliotecas. He leido que puede deberse a que python no está en tu PATH, aunque no veo la relación. Yo te aconsejaría instalar anaconda, que es una distro de python que tiene montones de paquetes ya precompilados para windows. Con anaconda instalado te bastaría hacer `conda install -c conda-forge pyproj `

Comment: Efectivamente, Con ananconda puede instalar pyproj, bockeh y panadas. muchas Gracias